Flutter built windows app not showing app state list in listview
Have never had this issue, but have not needed to build windows app yet.  However I have a page with 2 listviews that show an appstate List and are updated when a websocket message is recevied.  This works in a web build without issue, however when I either run windows in debug or a release build, the appstate variable showing the message works, but the listview does not show, just empty.  I can show alot of code, but with it working in web and mobile I am thinking I am missing something for windows.
Has anyone seen this before and have some advice?
TIA
